# Hbase shell Filter with Prefix

Tags: nosql, hbase, hbase-shell

I have to get all the entries from a HBASE table which have values substring of the given input.

For example if my table is like below:

```sh
Table   |   Family  |   ColumnQualifier |   Value
exp     |   family  |       column      |   1000xyz
exp     |   family  |       column1     |   1000abc
exp     |   family  |       column2     |   1001abc
```

I need to get the entries 1000xyz and 1000abc by value filter with input - 1000

I tried the value filter :

```sh
scan 'exp', { FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binary:1000')" }
```

which gives me the exact value 1000.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `binaryprefix` instead of `binary` as value comparator,

```
scan 'exp', { FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:1000' )" }
```